# Capture image repetitively from webcam and send the image using FTP

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, ftp, qt4

I want to create a function that is set to be repetitive, so whenever I execute the function, the program captures two images and send the image via FTP to an Android Smartphone. When I executed again, the program captures two new images and send them.

The capturing process works, the image can be successfully captured as many as I want. The problem is the sending process to the Android.

Here is the code:

```
QString nama = QString("webcam_capture_%1.jpg") .arg(QString::number(x));
imwrite(nama.toStdString(),leftcam);
file->setFileName(nama);
file->open(QFile::ReadOnly);
file2->open(QFile::ReadOnly);
ftp->put(file2,"text.txt");
ftp->put(file,nama);

x++;

sleep(2);

cap>>leftcam;

nama = QString("webcam_capture_%1.jpg") .arg(QString::number(x));
imwrite(nama.toStdString(),leftcam);
file3->setFileName(nama);
file3->open(QFile::ReadOnly);
ftp->put(file3,nama);
x++;
```

and this is the working code, but I manually name the picture.

```
imwrite("webcam_capture_0.jpg",leftcam);
cout<<"sending"<<endl;
file->setFileName("webcam_capture_0.jpg");
file2->setFileName("warningxx.txt");
file->open(QFile::ReadOnly);
file2->open(QFile::ReadOnly);
ftp->put(file2,"text.txt");
ftp->put(file,"webcam_capture_0.jpg");

sleep(2);

cap>>leftcam;

imwrite("webcam_capture_1.jpg",leftcam);
file3->setFileName("webcam_capture_1.jpg");
file3->open(QFile::ReadOnly);
ftp->put(file3,"webcam_capture_1.jpg");
```

My question is, why the first function does not work? The program captures images but does not send the image (and the text) to the Android smartphone.  Based on this [QFTP class reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qftp.html/) :

```
int put ( QIODevice * dev, const QString & file, TransferType type = Binary )
int put ( const QByteArray & data, const QString & file, TransferType type = Binary )
```

the `const QString &file`, the filename on the first function is already on QString.

How can I fix the problem?

I'm using Qt 4.8.2. Linux. Cubieboard 2 ARM MiniPC.

Comment: For starters change `nama = QString("webcam_capture_%1.jpg") .arg(QString::number(x));` to `nama = QString("webcam_capture_%1.jpg") .arg(x);` .arg() can use integers just fine no need to convert to a QString. Although I do not believe this is the problem. Just a code improvement.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and improvement. Yes it's not the problem. The program still does not work. I tried using qDebug() and the name is right, webcam_capture0 and webcam_capture1 and so on. I mean, the name is already same with the manual one. It should be working right?

Comment: I would verify that the file is actually being written in the first case.

Comment: The Images are captured in the first case, but they are not sent.